# Python Group Bar Chart Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I was trying to create group bar chart which can compare Time and its Mean value at the same time. the data is below:
[image]

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    bar_width = 0.35
    ind=np.arange(0, len(app_groups['TIME']))
    p1=ax.bar(ind+bar_width,app_groups['TIME'],bar_width)
    p2=ax.bar(ind+bar_width,app_groups['Mean'],bar_width)
    ax.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('TIME', 'MEAN'))
    plt.show()
```

However, I just got Stacked Bart Chart which is not what I want. 
[image]

Comment: Can you post your actual dataframe, as text, not as an image?

Comment: Also plz post a sample image what you want

Comment: Possibly you want to set the x positions to `ind-bar_width/2` and `ind+bar_width/2` respectively.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.  It works now.  but Still not be able add the APPL as my label

Comment: It's not written in the question, but if `app_groups` was a pandas DataFrame, you could also use pandas plotting wrapper like `app_groups.plot.bar()`